# HTTP error 502: Connection TImeout while using Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

I have tried many of the available solutions including fetch_openml(), but nothing has worked so far, what does deprecated means?
Can someone please help solve this?

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/deprecation.py:77: DeprecationWarning: Function fetch_mldata is deprecated; fetch_mldata was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in version 0.22
  warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/deprecation.py:77: DeprecationWarning: Function mldata_filename is deprecated; mldata_filename was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in version 0.22
  warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-24c62b1005d9> in <module>
----> 1 mnist=datasets.fetch_mldata('MNIST original')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/deprecation.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     76         def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
     77             warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
---> 78             return fun(*args, **kwargs)
     79 
     80         wrapped.__doc__ = self._update_doc(wrapped.__doc__)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/datasets/mldata.py in fetch_mldata(dataname, target_name, data_name, transpose_data, data_home)
    131         urlname = MLDATA_BASE_URL % quote(dataname)
    132         try:
--> 133             mldata_url = urlopen(urlname)
    134         except HTTPError as e:
    135             if e.code == 404:

/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221     else:
    222         opener = _opener
--> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    224 
    225 def install_opener(opener):

/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    530         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    531             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 532             response = meth(req, response)
    533 
    534         return response

/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    640         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    641             response = self.parent.error(
--> 642                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    643 
    644         return response

/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    568         if http_err:
    569             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 570             return self._call_chain(*args)
    571 
    572 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    502         for handler in handlers:
    503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 504             result = func(*args)
    505             if result is not None:
    506                 return result

/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    648 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    649     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 650         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    651 
    652 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Connection timed out
```

This error occured when I ran the above code in jupyter notebook. I also tried it in ipython and python3, all in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/issues/8#issuecomment-392002506

Comment: @desertnaut is there any other way to make it work?